# Unable to get session store value laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, session-variables

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnkPr.png)I'm storing my user id upon click of different users list using this method to store `user_id` in session

```
Session::put('user_id', $request->id);
```

and getting this `user_id` in another method of controller by using

```
$id = Session::get('user_id');
```

but each time I am getting the same id instead of a different upon clicking of different list users.
What am I doing wrong? Do I need to destroy the session? The session value is not overriding.

Comment: Did you check if you store in the session the good $request->id?

Comment: Yes, in the same method $request->id storing in session.

Answer (score 1):

You can use session global helper to store data in sessions

```
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

retrieve data using global helper

```
$value = session('key');
```

---

or you can use request instance

```
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');
```

retrieve data using request instance

```
$value = $request->session()->get('key', 'default');
```

more details [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session)

Comment: If I write above two lines session put and session get write next to each other in same method then I'm getting correct id and session value,but if I get in different method I'm not getting.why?

Comment: Actually,I'm setting session id in controller method calling from ajax.and the ajax method call upon onclick of user list.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the session user_id once after you use it, you can use following.

Retrieving And Deleting An Item.

```
$id = $request->session()->pull('user_id', 'default')]);
```

The pull method will retrieve and delete an item from the session
Read more : https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session

Comment: My session value is stored in session and I'm getting default answer by using your above line.which mean im not getting session value in different method but getting in same method of controller.

Comment: If you can, share the codes in controller or take a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Add below code on top of your class declaration

```
use Session;
```

and in your function add below code to print all the session values

```
$arrMixSessionData   = Session::all();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrMixSessionData);
echo '<pre/>';
```

To retrieve the selected session variable, you need to add request variable in the function declaration and use as below

```
function test(Request $request){
    $value = $request->session()->get('key', 'default');
}
```

Hopes it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
Array
(
    [_previous] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://localhost/marketplace/public/update-service
        )

    [_flash] => Array
        (
            [old] => Array
                (
                )

            [new] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [_token] => aUhfVMGSeefkELlfAv15uYMCnymUteDp5PENQ8p6
    [login_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d] => 1
    [user_id] => 7
)
I called this method where I store session,my id is setting as 7.

Comment: but If I call the same method where i want to retreive session value,this method return empty array.why?

Comment: why don't you use like $arrMixSessionData['user_id'], or send me your function code, I'll check on it.

Comment: or try like this Session::get('user_id');

Comment: public function consumerProfile(Request $request){
        $id = $request->session()->pull('user_id', 'default');

        $modal = modal::where('user_id' , $id)->first();
        $booking = Booking::where('user_id' , $id)->first();
        $user = User::where('id' , $id)->first();

        return view('consumer.consumerProfile' , compact('modal','booking', 'user'));
    }
    public function customerDetail(Request $request){
        $data = array();

        $request->session()->put('user_id' , $request->id);

        echo json_encode($data);
        exit();
    }

Comment: in below function session is setting its verified but in above method i'm getting it but it return default not getting

Comment: both the methods are in same controller.

Comment: can you try with Session::get('user_id');

Comment: I just want to highlight you when you use session pull it will get the value and delete from session, I think it could be deleted when you try to access on the second time. so try $id = $request->session()->get('user_id');

Comment: $id = $request->session()->get('user_id'); not working.
It should not be deleted.

Comment: have you tried to re login again and do the text after update session get code?

Comment: try this instead of fetching id

Comment: $arrMixSessionData = $request->session()->all(); 
var_dump($arrMixSessionData);

Comment: array(4) { ["_previous"]=> array(1) { ["url"]=> string(50) "http://localhost/marketplace/public/update-service" } ["_flash"]=> array(2) { ["old"]=> array(0) { } ["new"]=> array(0) { } } ["_token"]=> string(40) "Qfbw8p3zwaiB3ijadIJiUOBjc3c7dxd4R8cuJF3h" ["login_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d"]=> int(1) }

Comment: array(5) { ["_previous"]=> array(1) { ["url"]=> string(50) "http://localhost/marketplace/public/update-service" } ["_flash"]=> array(2) { ["old"]=> array(0) { } ["new"]=> array(0) { } } ["_token"]=> string(40) "Qfbw8p3zwaiB3ijadIJiUOBjc3c7dxd4R8cuJF3h" ["login_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d"]=> int(1) ["user_id"]=> string(1) "7" }

Comment: first function where Im setting session has user_id whereas where I'm getting don't have.

Comment: Hi Asim, add me in skype carthik.s will sort it out together.

Comment: my id is carthik.s